# How to avoid to duplicate columns when getting a table from a json element

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have a json element with this structure

> array of letter(A,B,C or D):
>
> - _1,
>
>   ```
>   -start
>   - end
>   ```
> - _2,

> ```
>     -start
>     -end
> ```
>
> - _3,

> ```
>   -start
>   -end
> ```

I would like to obtain a table like this

> | obj_type | 1_start | 1_end | 2_start | 2_end | 3_start | 3_end |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | value | value | value | value | value | value |
> | B | value | value | value | value | value | value |
> | C | value | value | value | value | value | value |

value can be null

```
WITH d (department_data) AS (SELECT (UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw ('{
  "r": [
    {
      "obj_type": "A",
      "_1":  {
        "start": "1",
        "end": "2"
        },
        "_2":  {
        "start": "15",
        "end": "25"
        },
        "_3":  {
        "start": "26",
        "end": "33"
        }
    },
    {
      "obj_type": "B",
      "_1": {
        "start": "1",
        "end": "2"
    },
        "_2":  {
        "start": "3",
        "end": "12"
        }
    },    {
      "obj_type": "C",
      "_2":{
        "start": "1",
        "end": "2"
    }
    },    {
      "obj_type": "D",
      "_3": {
        "start": "",
        "end": "2"
    }
    }
  ]
}')) FROM DUAL)
--select * from d;
SELECT j.*
  FROM d,
       JSON_TABLE (
           d.department_data,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (

               NESTED PATH '$.r[*]'
                    COLUMNS (
                        name PATH '$.obj_type', 
                        NESTED PATH '$._1[*]'
                            columns ("_1_start" PATH '$.start',
                                     "_2_end" PATH '$.end'),
                        NESTED PATH '$."_2"[*]'
                            columns ("UVG_start" PATH '$.start',
                                     "UVG - Zusatz_end" PATH '$.end'),
                        NESTED PATH '$."_3"[*]'
                            columns ("UVG - Ueberschusslohn_start" PATH '$.start',
                                     "UVG - Ueberschusslohn_end" PATH '$.end')
                            ))) j
```

This query is not returning what I've expected.

The lines are duplicated. start and end from _1 are not the same line of start and end from _2.
Furthermore  if there is no value they are not printed.

to summarize, something like this

> | obj_type | 1_start | 1_end | 2_start | 2_end | 3_start | 3_end |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | value | value | nothing | nothing | nothing | nothing |
> | A | nothing | nothing | value | value | nothing | nothing |
> | A | nothing | nothing | nothing | nothing | value | value |

same thing with B and C

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0361ee0c6ed4d81ec7ada9ca38262947)

Comment: Kindly format the question properly

Comment: @Nishant Gupta I think the format is better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example data you don't need the repeated `nested path` elements, you can just do:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM d
CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE (
  d.department_data,
  '$'
  COLUMNS (
    NESTED PATH '$.r[*]'
    COLUMNS (
      name PATH '$.obj_type', 
      "_1_start" PATH '$."_1".start',
      "_1_end" PATH '$."_1".end',
      "_2_start" PATH '$."_2".start',
      "_2_end" PATH '$."_2".end',
      "_3_start" PATH '$."_3".start',
      "_3_end" PATH '$."_3".end'
    )
  )
) j
```

| NAME | _1_start | _1_end | _2_start | _2_end | _3_start | _3_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 15 | 25 | 26 | 33 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 3 | 12 | *null* | *null* |
| C | *null* | *null* | 1 | 2 | *null* | *null* |
| D | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 2 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f74843919a168e3f7de727ab9f6c2bd9)